# How to get all entries out of a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to build a ul by pull the content out of a SQL table. But this code does only gives me the first row. What would be the best solution to get all 10 entries?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `activitys`";

echo '<td><ul>';

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo "<li>".$row['content']."</li>";

}

echo '<td><ul>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in a loop, like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li>".$row['content']."</li>";
}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage compared to "for each"?

Comment: @HamburgIsNice Roughly, while you're building a PHP array out of a data base result, use while. Once you have that array, use foreach - although I'm sure the real answer is much more nuanced.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a while loop.  That way it will keep going until the end.  An IF only runs once.